# Neo4j PHP Acquire wirte lock

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp

Sinking in big trouble,

Well can anyone tell me , how can i acquire write lock through cypher.
Note : I will use REST APIs , So my cypher would in php.

EDITED : 
Scenario:

I am using Neo4j REST server and PHP to access it.

Now i have created a node say 'counter-node' which generates new user id. Logic is just add 1 to previous value.

Now If two users are coming simultaneously then first user read 'counter-node' value BUT before it can update it to 1 , second user read it . Thus value in 'counter-node' is not as expected.

Any Help

Comment: what's the use case, i.e. why do you need to do that in the first place?

Comment: @Michal : Hello Michal , I added scenario :) . I hope it is understandable

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to acquire write locks explicitly. All nodes that you modify in a transaction are write-locked automatically.

So if you do this in your logic:

```
start tx
increment counter node
read the value of the counter node and set it on the user node as ID
commit tx
```

no two users will ever get the same ID.

Comment: Hey thanks for correcting my concept and most importantly can you suggest me which neo4jPHP should I use. Any suggestions

Comment: The problem with this Michal is that two threads can still read the old value at the same time and the write the **same** oldvalue + 1 to the property. So a write lock before the first read is required. Kind of indicating that you want to read/write as an atomic operation.

Comment: That's why I suggested the increment first, then read the value? Will that not solve the problem?

Comment: Nah, ok, I see what you're saying

Comment: @MichaelHunger: One thing is not clear, When i am writting something inside transaction then isn't it transaction that do all locking process .. Why I need to explicitly acquire read or write lock ?

Comment: OK, thinking about this, my answer is plain wrong. I don't think there's a way to do this atomically in Cypher; is the only solution a Java plugin then? In that case, I should update the answer, so it doesn't confuse people... Michael?

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480505/what-does-transaction-mean-in-reference-with-neo4j-database/18486645#18486645

Answer (score 1):

The popular [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) plugin for Neo4j has a selection of explicit Locking procedures that can be called via Cypher such as `call apoc.lock.nodes([nodes])`

Learn more at [neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_locking](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_locking)

*Note: as far as I can tell, this functionality doesn't exist natively in Cypher so APOC is probably your best bet.*