# Spring Data neo4j isolation level

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

my current project shows a lost-update problem because two different threads load and save a neo4j DynamicProperties field. There is a really good explanation of the problem in another stackoverflow question ([what does transaction mean in reference with neo4j database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480505/what-does-transaction-mean-in-reference-with-neo4j-database)). Hence, I want to change neo4j to "repeatable read" isolation level, but I cannot figure out how to do that. There is no neo4j or spring data neo4j documentation about how to change it.

I use spring data neo4j version 3.0.0.RC1 and with neo4j 2.0.1 and I use a simple configuration:

```
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />
<bean id="graphDataBaseFactory" class="org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory"/>
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" factory-bean="graphDataBaseFactory" factory-method="newEmbeddedDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${database.neo4j.storedirectory}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? would appreciate if you can share your findings

Comment: unfortunately not. I had to change the database because of other requirements.