# Access Java functionalities through php

Tags: java, php, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am planning to use the Neo4j(graph database)embedded server . I plan to write a class in java to interact with a database, but while using PHP as the server language (Apache).

How can I evoke the java function from PHP to get data from the database?

Please give me some stable solution as I am going to suggest this to my team.

Comment: Why don't you write a class in PHP to interact with database?

Comment: use web service in that java class

Comment: @RoyalBg : Problem is I am not able to acquire write lock to node . Here is my question regarding that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480064/neo4j-php-acquire-wirte-lock#comment27174495_18480064

Comment: @LS97 : Can I know what this question has been down voted ?? Or just because you donot like ???

Comment: I don't even have the permission to downvote questions, so it wasn't me...

Comment: @LS97 : Ok , then some one else .. :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider writing a Neo4j server plugin in Java, then accessing it via REST through PHP. See here http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-plugins.html